# How can I make swinging barn doors weather tight?

Tags: exterior, temperature, weatherstripping

Looking to turn a small barn-type structure into a climate controlled woodshop. The building itself is block and the doors are about 4x10' (w/h) oak pivoting double doors like a shed would have.

I want to keep these doors (instead of investing in an expensive rollup, etc.) but is there a good way to make them more airtight? I plan to try to keep the shop temp/humidity on a thermostat.

Comment: They aren't French doors unless they have a grid of glass panes in them. Otherwise they're just double swinging doors. Believe it or not I have seen a shed with French doors--my father built a "sugar shack" for maple syrup production with some repurposed glass panel doors. I doubt that your barn has them.

Comment: The answer is in the details here. Photos are almost required.

Answer (score 2):

Without pictures or a description of what you've currently got to make them "airtight", it's hard to make a specific recommendation, but in general, do the same things you do for French doors on your house:

- Weather stripping all around the openings
- Weather stripping between the doors
- Rubber sweeps at the bottom of the doors

If the doors weren't originally designed for weatherstripping, adding it may make it very difficult to close them, so you may have to either get some very thin rubber or foam gaskets, or, using some of those woodworking tools in your woodworking shop, adapt the doors and/or openings to make room for thicker weatherstripping.

Whatever you do, just make sure that the doors close tightly and that your updates don't prevent the latches from working.

Comment: Do you know anybody who makes/provides air-tight storm doors? May help on top of all the measures you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the suggestions in Freeman's answer - which are good you need to go back to design principles of the doors.

One door should have an in inset and this can range in thickness to what you want and need (thicker for insulated or sturdier door).   Let's call this door B.

The other door should be outset (door A) - in that the backing of the door extends beyond the frame and covers the section of door B that is inset.

(To make things more confusing you)... you can alternatively cover the outside of your doors in an outset/inset fashion so that one overlap the other.   The gap for the overlap being 4"+ from the door frame gap protects it from weather.   A gasket or weather stripping in the gap helps too.

It really is determinant on what your current door situation looks like and how bad (and where?  top/side/what) the weather issues are.   For instance if I decide off offset the door outside I will also have to install trim around the doors so that the new raised panels' edges are protected.

If I protect inside I might not be solving all of the issues as the offset wouldn't necessarily protect weather from the top of the doors any better (it could but not innate).   So that may not work or I still may need to install trim to help.

With pictures of your current situation I could probably guess which route you should take.